# Small resolution on the big screen

Tags: display, multiple-monitors

I have two 2560x1440 screens per user.

Generally my PCs have two Display Ports. No problems. This just works.
However I have a user that has a computer with VGA and DVI.

When I connect this users displays to the DVI & HDMI from her graphics card I run into a problem. The DVI port works just fine, but the monitor connected to the HDMI output only show is 19 ?? X1xxx!

How is this possible?

The Voison the same (HDMI & DVI) and everything is OK!

The GPU can do something? GPUs are not identical on the two people ...

Comment: Dp has no problems with high resolutions. Neither has dual-link DVI. However older HDMI standards are limited, usually resulting in max 1920x1200. Can you check the HDMI version on the user which gets the unexpected low resolution? (And post that using the [edit](http://superuser.com/posts/1106015/edit) link.

Comment: Hello Hennes, thanks for the answer ! how i can check the HDMI version ?

Comment: It should be in the manual of the graphics card. Can you post the model of the card used ?

Comment: The model is ATI Radeaon HD 4300/4500 Series (that the manager device tell me)

Comment: That is a model introduced in 2009. Best I can find is http://www.uni-kl.de/elektronik-lager/DV2117 this manual, which indeed shows max 1920x.... on the HDMI port. Your model might be different, but it is a reasonably safe bet that you simply cannot get 2560x1440 from that HDMI port.  Simplest and cheapest solution which I see is sadly new hardware (just about any modern EUR50/$60 card should do). :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are running into a bandwidth limitation here. In order to support 2560x1440, you need a dual link DVI cable.

As far as I'm aware of, there is no Dual Link DVI to HDMI cable, so either get a monitor that supports HDMI with the appropriate cable that supports high bandwidth, or use an adapter.

Please note that display port does not have a version with this limitation, so it will always work. If this is an option, display port is the preferred option.

EDIT: It appears that the videocard you're using does not support HDMI with a bandwidth higher of 1920x1200. (tnx Hennes) So you will have to replace or add a videocard.

Comment: I do not really understand what you say ...
I have a user with the same connections (HDMI & DVI), which has two screens at 2540x1440.
But the user in question (which has the same connections) has her screen in 2540 in DVI but not HDMI ...

Yet you tell me to take a monitor that supports HDMI? ...

Sorry my English is not great.

Comment: @OP has Two displays per screen and uses two outputs on the computer. No attempt is made to convert from one output to the other output. Monitors seem to accept DP, DVI and HDMI.